# optimize query with date type field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I currently have the following query prepared:

```
select sum(amount) as total 
  from incomes 
 where (YEAR(date) = '2019' and MONTH(date) = '07') 
   and incomes.deleted_at is null
```

when reviewing it a bit, notice that it takes too long to have a lot of data in the table, since it goes through all this. I do not know much about optimizing queries, but I want to start documenting and researching for this case, reading a little note that although it is possible to create an `index` for a date type field, `MySQL` will not use an index once a column of the `WHERE` clause is wrapped with a function in this case `YEAR` and `MONTH`. So is this correct? What steps should I follow to improve its performance? Should I try to restructure my query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select sum(i.amount) as total
from incomes i
where i.date >= '2019-07-01' and
      i.date < '2019-08-01' and
      i.deleted_at is null;
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `incomes(deleted_at, date, amount)`:

```
create index idx_incomes_deleted_at_date_amount on incomes(deleted_at, date, amount)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I do not understand this part well: `incomes (deleted_at, date, amount)` means that I must create an index composed of these 3 columns? or for this case based on the query of your answer, an index for the date column is sufficient

Comment: And the change to the `WHERE` makes it 'sargable'.